# zsh: Unable to bind ^q or \M-q in vi mode

Tags: zsh

My .zshrc file contains the line

```
bindkey -v
```

I'm attempting to bind ^q or \M-q to push-line, e.g.

```
bindkey "^q" push-line
```

but for some reason it isn't working.

Running `bind key -v' confirms

```
"^Q" push-line
```

But it doesn't actually do anything. Other control- mappings, such as ^r, work fine.

I can successfully map "push-line" to "\eq", but I don't like this behavior. First of all, I never use esc- type bindings, and secondly doing so binds it to control, meta, and escape, which is overkill. (Incidentally, shouldn't it only bind all of them like that with `bindkey -m'? I never set that in my .zshrc?)

So, anybody have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These shortcuts are used by [Software flow control (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control)

`Ctrl+S` and `Ctrl+Q` are used to stop and resume the output of a program.

To try it:
Run `while (true) ; do echo $RANDOM ; sleep 1 ; done`
Press `Ctrl+S`, the output stop.
Press `Ctrl+Q`, the output resume.
(I'm not sure the program is stopped like with `Ctrl+Z`, i think it is stuck by lack of outputting. `Ctrl+C` to kill the program.)

These shortcuts take over your shortcuts, but if you disable this flow control feature, it could work.
You can learn how to disable it in [How to unfreeze after accidentally pressing Ctrl-S in a terminal? - Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12107/how-to-unfreeze-after-accidentally-pressing-ctrl-s-in-a-terminal).
Try it and tell us.

Comment: If you suspend a program with Ctrl-z, you can resume it with the "fg" command.

Comment: Also, I should be able to bind meta-q, since as far as I can tell there are no meta- bindings at all (at least on my system), but that doesn't work either. And, I'll reiterate, "\eq" binds escape-e, meta-q, and ctrl-q all at once – and ctrl-q works in that case without needing to disable flow control.

Comment: I bound "^Q end-of-line", it didn't work, i ran `stty -ixon` and then the shortcut worked, with emacs or vi mode. (I usually use emacs mode). So i'm not sure i can reproduce your problem. Try more and look for info in `man zshzle` or give precise command to try and i can tell you what happens for me. I use zsh 4.3.10, and you?

Comment: Well, mine behaves the same way. I do find it a little counterintuitive that start/stop input control must be explicitly disabled using '^q' but not '\eq'.